# Restore Macbook 2009 backup from Timemachine

Tags: macbook-pro, restore

How do I restore the latest backup from the Time Machine and get all the data/desktop - in fact all the files including the OS Yosemite?

Genius support installed a new battery so working off a clean install. The automated Restore from Time Machine / Macbook only installed basic version and not the applications such as MS office or any document files.

Comment: Is it now common practice for Apple to wipe your hard drive when installing a new battery? To be honest, this seems very unlikely. What there also a hard drive failure?

Answer (score 1):

**Standard method for recovery from Time Machine**

- Power up your Mac and hold down the command and R keys to enter the Recovery Partition. Your Mac should boot to a screen that says OS X Utilities.
- Select Restore from Time Machine Backup and click Continue.
- Read the info on the Restore Your System page and click Continue.
- Select your Time Machine backup and click Continue.
- Select the most recent backup of your hard disk and click Continue. Your Mac will then restore the Time Machine backup; once it's done it will restart.

If you've had to replace your Mac's hard drive with a raw drive fresh out of the box, there's no recovery partition to restore from. But fear not, you can get the recovery rolling from the Time Machine backup disk itself. Just hold down the Option key when you start your Mac; you'll be able to select the Time Machine backup disk as your startup, instead.

*Source :* http://www.imore.com/how-set-and-restore-time-machine-backup

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at the detailed information contained in the Pondini website. Unfortunately, Mr. Ponds has passed away, but his advice is still awesome.

You will want to use Setup Assistant or Migration Assistant.

http://pondini.org/OSX/Setup.html

Comment: linked site is offline :/

Comment: Try this https://web.archive.org/web/20170623091904/http://pondini.org/TM/Home.html